# Vis viva equation - finding how change in velocity changes the semi-major axis distances - math trick

Tags: orbital-motion, differentiation, celestial-mechanics, calculus

I'm reading about how to deorbit. I stumped upon a trick [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12011/how-could-a-90-m-s-delta-v-be-enough-to-commit-the-space-shuttle-to-landing/12036#12036). In the question, we wish to find how a chance in orbital speed changes the semi-major axis distances. So in the answer we start with the [Vis Viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation):

$$ v^2 = GM(\frac2r-\frac1a)$$

and assume we have a circular orbit, $r = a$. Then we rewrite the equation:
$$ v^2 = GM\frac1a.$$

**Here comes the trick I don't understand. We now rewrite that equation to:**

$$2v \thinspace dv = \frac{GM}{a^2} da.$$

How is that possible? I would love to know how this is done.

I can see it makes sense, since taking the integration restores the original equation.  It also seems like he could be multiplying with $\frac{d}{dv\thinspace da}$ on both sides, but now I'm just guessing.

Comment: What is the difficulty? The step you point out is obtained by differentiating the previous eqn (with a minus missing). Treating parameter $a$ as a variable. Is this really what you don't understand?? If it is not this which is puzzling you then what is it?

Comment: Just operate $d$ on both sides of the equation: $d(v^2) = d(GM\frac1a).$ Note, $d(1/a)=-1/a^2$. The answer you provided is for constant $r$.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm still a little confused. How does the $d$ operator leave us with $dv$ and $da$? It should just return the term differentiated. Also why does the operator hit $v^2$ and $\frac{1}{a}$. but not for example $G$? It's like cheery picking to me.

Comment: $G$ and $M$ are constant, and $a$ and $v$ change over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical exercise in calculus so I would recommend brushing up.

Given your equation:
$$v^2 = GM\left( \frac{2}{r} - \frac{1}{a}\right)$$
you want to ask how the RHS changes when you change the LHS. I.e. you apply the differential operator $d$.
$$\frac{d(v^2)}{dv} = 2v \iff d(v^2) = 2vdv$$
$$\frac{d}{da} GM\left(\frac{2}{r} - \frac{1}{a}\right) = \frac{GM}{a^2} \iff d\left(GM\left(\frac{2}{r} - \frac{1}{a}\right)\right) = \frac{GMda}{a^2}$$.

Comment: Thank you cleared things up for me. Just to be clear would you instead use \frac{d}{dt} on both sides? so multiply with the same operator on both sides fo the equation?

Comment: There's no need to differentiate with respect to time here. All you are doing is trying to figure out _how much a changes when v changes_. Since you have complex functions of $a$ and $v$, you need to first figure out how those functions change as $a$ and $v$ change.